# Send an email to all contacts that can manage an organization's membership

Tags: civimail, civimember, groups

Scenario:
Membership by organization - each organization has at least one contact person that is an individual that has contact permissions.

I want to send an email to each member organization's email and each individual that has edit privileges for those member organizations.

Comment: Have you tried the Reports - Contact Reports - Relationships report? It might get you close, and then you can add the results to a group and send the group an email.

Comment: So I added all the organizations with membership to a group. Unfortunately you cannot say Contact A is in a group & Contact B has permission to edit Contact A but is not in that group.

If there was a membership filter or contact A/B group filter - I think this could work.